# Data fetched from JSON is logged multiple times on pressing Enter key

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsx

I am making a search functionality in my React website, when the user enter a keyword in the search input the keyword is matched in json, if the same is found in it then `yes` is logged, or else nothing is logged in the console.

Here is what my JSON looks like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "iPhone 12 Space Black",
    "price": "1,12,322" ,
    "description": "",
    "rating": 4.8 ,
    "stock": "in stock",
    "image": "",
    "key": ["mobile", "iphone", "apple"]
  },
   {
    "name": "OnePlus 9",
    "price":"58,999",
    "description": "",
    "rating": 4.2,
    "stock": "out of stock",
    "image": "",
    "key": ["mobile", "one plus", "oneplus"]

  }, 
   {
    "name": "Google Pixel 5",
    "price": "78,654",
    "description": "",
    "rating": 3.4 ,
    "stock": "in stock",
    "image": "",
    "key": ["google", "mobile", "pixel", "google pixel"]
  }, 

//The rest of the JSON

]
```

So as you can se it is an array of object, each object is having an array of key(keywords), if any member of key is matched with the value inputed by the user it should log `yes`.

Here is the JSX

```
//React, css and all other imports
import {searchClick} from "../javascript/productSearch.js"


export default function Navbar() {
function onKeyPress() {
  var input = document.getElementById("search-input");
  
  input.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      document.getElementById("search-btn").click();
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}

return(
<div>
//Some Code
         <div className="header-search-form">
              <input id="search-input" 
                     onKeyUp={onKeyPress()} 
                     type="text" 
                     placeholder="Enter a keword to search...." />
              <button id="search-btn" onClick={searchClick}>
                   <img src={searchIcon} width="25px" /> 
              </button>
        </div>
//Some code
</div>

)}
```

When the user clicks the search icon in the search input or press enter, the Javascript runs, here's the JS:

```
export function searchClick() {
    console.log("fun working");
    var searchQuery = document.querySelector("#search-input").value;
    console.log(searchQuery);

    if(searchQuery === "")
    console.log("null");
    else extarctJSON()

     function extarctJSON() {
        fetch("./json/products.json")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {

        console.log(data);
        
        var len = data.length;
        
        for(var i=0;i<len;i++) {
            var keyLen = data[i].key.length;
            for(var j=0;j<keyLen;j++) {
                if(data[i].key[j] === searchQuery) {
                    console.log("yes");
                    break;
                } 
            }
        }
    })  
    }
  
    }
```

So the loop checks all the objects in the JSON array, and in every object it search for the `searchQuery` in the key array, if found the loop breaks and logs `yes` and same process is followed for the rest of the objects in the JSON array.

I hope I explained what I am trying to do, now here is the problem which I am getting:

**PROBLEM**
When the user clicks on the `#search-btn` image he gets the desired output, as for mobile he will get 3 yes, but when he presses enter instead of clicking on the `#search-btn` he gets multiple time yes, which is more than the actual objects matching the keyword.

I am trying to solve this problem from a long time but nothing seems to work and I am not getting any clue where I am wrong actually.

Here is the LIVE website on [Netlify](https://thedukaandar.netlify.app/)
Here is the full JSON so that you can try different keywords in it [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/vVr31udi)

I hope I will find the solution to this problem , Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide your onKeyPress function?

Comment: @tagir it is there in JS, searchClick() in the answer, see.

Comment: No, I'm talking about onKeyPress function inside your input.  onKeyUp={onKeyPress}

Comment: I've checked your sources from link. In your onKeyPress function you use  var input = document.getElementById("search-input"); You should use react-way to hande events

Comment: @tagir I am so sorry, i was trying different things so it left out, it is searchClick, i updated it in the question

Comment: @tagir can you elaborate what is react-way?

Comment: Look at my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only a little bit of JavaScript needs to be updated:

```
function onKeyPress() {
  var input = document.getElementById("search-input");
  
  input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      document.getElementById("search-btn").click();
      //Add this line
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
  });
}
```

`event.stopImmediatePropagation();` stops all other listeners of the event.

Answer (score 0):

In your onKeyUp you need to handle only Enter button press.

```js
onKeyPress = (event) => {
  if(event.key === 'Enter'){
    searchClick();
  }
}
```

```html
import {searchClick} from "../javascript/productSearch.js"


export default function Navbar() {

return(
<div>
//Some Code
         <div className="header-search-form">
              <input id="search-input" 
                     onKeyUp={onKeyPress} 
                     type="text" 
                     placeholder="Enter a keword to search...." />
              <button id="search-btn" onClick={searchClick}>
                   <img src={searchIcon} width="25px" /> 
              </button>
        </div>
//Some code
</div>

)}
```